# understanding what is happening in spark execution plan

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given the following spark execution plan [image]

I am calling `count()` a few times, but it looks like the stage gets repeated for each count call. Is that because I'm not caching the dataframe?

Comment: 1) This is not an execution plan. It's a graphical representation of Spark's event log. 2) You are right, in this log several stage groups are repeated multiple times because the resulting dataframe is not cached.